# Como exibir o resultado de uma query numa página html em PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

Como eu posso exibir os resultados de uma query numa tabela de uma página html?

Abaixo segue o que consegui fazer. No entanto, o código mostra somente o primeiro registro.

```php
include("conectar.php");
$sql = mysql_query("Select * From tb_trabalhador and tb_detalhe_trabalhador");
$exibe = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
echo "<table>"; 
echo  "<tr><td>Nome:</td>";
echo "<td>".$exibe["Nome"]."</td></tr>"; e os outros campos
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Quando mais de um resultado é retornado pela sua consulta, utilize um `while` para obter todos eles.

```
$sql = mysql_query("Select * From tb_trabalhador and tb_detalhe_trabalhador");
while($exibe = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
  echo $exibe['nome'] .'<br>';
}
```

Recomendo utilizar o [mysql_error()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php) para debugar seu código e obter uma mensagem de erro do banco, caso esse seja um projeto legado.

```
mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

É altamente recomendavel utilizar o [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) ou [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) para efetuar conexão com banco de dados, pois as funções `mysql_*` já foram descontinuados e logo serão removidas.

[Motivos para não utilizar as funções mysql_*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/579/porque-nao-devemos-usar-funcoes-do-tipo-mysql)

Comment: Muito obrigado. So uma outra questão.
Quando vou mostrar o dado quero que ele me mostro o resultado se estiver preenchido ou me mostre (N/A). Code:
echo "<td>".(!empty($exibe["Morada"]) ? $exibe["Morada"] : "(N/A)")."</td></tr>";

Duplica-me os dados ao mostrar como está

Comment: Adicine um if dentro do while,
`if($exibir['nome']){
   echo $exibir['nome'];
}else{
   echo 'N/D';
}`

Comment: echo "<td>";
    if (trim($exibe['Morada']) != "") {echo   $exibe['Morada'];} else {echo "N/D";}
   echo "</td></tr>";

os meus dados continuama ser mostrados duas vezes S:

Comment: Algum problema com a resposta?

Answer (score 2):

Todas funções mysql_fetch_* retornam uma única linha e avançam o cursor interno para o próximo registro.

Para obter todos os registros, você precisa utiliza-las dentro de alguma estrutura de repetição.

Exemplo:

```
while ($exibe = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql) ) { // Obtém os dados da linha atual e avança para o próximo registro
  echo $exibe["nome"];
}
```

Conforme mencionado, considere utilizar uma extensão PDO para gerenciar a comunicação entre aplicação <-> banco de dados, tendo em vista que estas funções de baixo nível serão futuramente removidas.

Answer (score 2):

Para obter todos os registros você precisa de uma laço de repetição:

```
include("conectar.php");
$sql = mysql_query("Select * From tb_trabalhador and tb_detalhe_trabalhador");
echo "<table>";
while($exibe = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
   echo "<tr><td>Nome:</td>";
   echo "<td>".$exibe["Nome"]."</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: o tag <table> fica fora do laço de repetição. Senão vai criar uma tabela para cada linha. E o fechamento da </table> também fica depois do while

Answer (score 0):

É importante ressaltar que queries não devem ser executadas em uma view. O correto é que você aplique um pattern MVC( Model View Controller) e separe as coisas. Um bom exemplo, utilizando o Framework Code Igniter, seria:

```
model.php
function carregar_trabalhador(){
$banco = new mysqli("servidor","usuário","senha");
$sql="Select * From tb_trabalhador and tb_detalhe_trabalhador";
$resultadoConsulta=$banco->query($sql);
$trabalhadores = array();
$i=0;
        while (!empty($resultadoConsulta[$i])) {
            $row = $resultadoConsulta[$i]=
            $trabalhadores[] = $row;
            $i++;
        }

return $resultadoConsulta
}

controller.php 
function exibir_trabalhador(){
$model= new Model();
$trabalhadores = $model->carregar_trabalhador(); 
$this->load->view("trabalhador.html", $trabalhadores);  
}

trabalhador.html
<?php
foreach ($trabalhadores as $trabalhador) {
?>
<table> 
    <tr><td>Nome:</td> 
        <td><?= $trabalhador["Nome"] ?></td></tr>; e os outros campos
    <?php }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$connection = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "pass", "database");
$sql = $connection->query("Select * From tb_trabalhador and tb_detalhe_trabalhador");

if($sql){ // If $sql is True
    while($exibe = $sql->fetch_assoc()){
        foreach($exibe as $key => $value){
            echo "<br />" . $value;
        }

    }
}
```

Esta forma isenta o uso destas tags html em seu código. O foreach exibe todas as informações, sem precisar especificar o que deve ser exibido, simplificando o seu código, ex. $exibe["Nome"].