# Listar consulta ao banco de dados em duas colunas para o usuario. - PHP

Tags: php, banco-de-dados

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema simples para ir praticando meus conhecimentos e estou em um momento que desejo realizar uma consulta ao banco de dados e retonar na tela em duas colunas, a parte da consulta está ok, porém lista todos os dados um embaixo do outro e nao quero que fique assim, alguem saberia como me ajudar?

quero que fique mais ou menos assim:

....
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

e o código está assim:

```
<?php
    include "conexao.php";

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios";
    $query = mysql_query($sql);
    $row = mysql_num_rows($query);
    $i = 0;

    while($linha = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
        $id = $linha['id'];
        $nome = $linha['nome'];
        $email = $linha['email'];

    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para isso você deve utilizar HTML e seguir uma estrutura semelhante a essa bastando fazer as alterações de HTML que desejar:

```
echo "<table>";
while($linha = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
 echo "<tr><td>id:</td>";
 echo "<td>".$linha["id"]."</td>";
 echo "<tr><td>nome:</td>";
 echo "<td>".$linha["nome"]."</td>";
 echo "<tr><td>email:</td>";
 echo "<td>".$linha["email"]."</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

E recomendo que você de uma pesquisada antes de abrir novas perguntas pois já existia uma muito semelhante a sua aqui mesmo no stack : [Como exibir o resultado de uma query numa página html em PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3567/como-exibir-o-resultado-de-uma-query-numa-p%C3%A1gina-html-em-php)