# Como faço para aparecer o resultado da pesquisa no banco?

Tags: php, mysqli

Tenho a seguinte linha no código na minha página `variaveis.php`

```
$selficha = mysqli_query($conexao,"SELECT deus FROM ficha WHERE nome='$user->username'");

$ficha = mysqli_fetch_row($selficha);
```

Incluí ela na página `ficha.php`, mas quando dou `print $ficha` pra mostrar o resultado, aparece `Array` ao invés do dado.

Comment: Você já estudou *array* do PHP?

Comment: E ai  Rafael, tranquilo no rio nilo ?! 

acho que esse link pode te ajuda 

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3567/como-exibir-o-resultado-de-uma-query-numa-p%C3%A1gina-html-em-php


Boa sorte !

Answer (score 0):

> Incluí ela na página ficha.php, mas quando dou print $ficha pra mostrar o resultado, aparece Array ao invés do dado.

Com a função `mysqli_fetch_row()`, você terá um retorno em forma de vetor/lista (não associativa). Sendo assim, deve exibir seu valor assim:

```
print($ficha[0]);
//print($ficha[1]);
// ...
```

> Referência: [PHP - mysqli_fetch_row](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php);
>
> Leitura recomendada: [PHP - Arrays](https://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.array.php)

Answer (score 0):

Deu certo! É que eu estava procurando assim antes disso tudo:
$selficha = mysqli_query($conexao,"SELECT * FROM ficha WHERE nome='$user->username'");

$ficha = mysqli_fetch_row($selficha);

E depois no print $ficha[deus] não estava aparecendo nada